# IndexError: list assignment index out of range 'xxx';'xxx'

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, indexing

I am creating a project called OpenCity which contains a premium version. The premium package is the problem.

The project hierarchy is:

```
opencity // is a project in PyCharm 2019.3
      premium // is a package
             __init__.py // is a module
             premium.py // is a module
             premium_user.py // is a module
             premium_user.txt // is a text file
```

premium_user.py:

```
import random as ran


def premium_users_adder():
    premium_user1a = open('premium_user.txt', 'a')
    # premium_user1w = open('premium_user.txt', 'w')
    # premium_user1r = open('premium_user.txt', 'r')
    p2 = int(input("How many members do you want to add to premium_users to database? "))
    p1 = []
    p3 = []
    for i in range(p2):
        member = input("Type the person's name. ")
        p1.append(member)
        id1 = ran.randint(100000000, 99999999999)
        p3.append(str(id1))
    for i, e in zip(p1, p3):
        premium_user1a.write(i + ' ' + e + '\n')
    premium_user1a.close()
    print()
    print("Done")


def premium_users_checker():
    premium_user1r = open('premium_user.txt', 'r')
    p2 = []
    p4 = []
    p5 = []
    for data in premium_user1r:
        p2.append(data)
    for i in range(len(p2)):
        x = int(i)
        p4[x], p5[x] = p2[x].split(' ')
    print(p4, p5)
```

premium.py:

```
import premium_users as pu

pu.premium_users_checker()
```

Error when running premium.py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/PyCharm Python Works/OpenCity/premium/premium.py", line 3, in <module>
    pu.premium_users_checker()
  File "F:\PyCharm Python Works\OpenCity\premium\premium_users.py", line 32, in premium_users_checker
    p4[x], p5[x] = p2[x].split(' ')
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I have given everything except the `premium_users.txt` which contains premium codes.

Comment: index `x` on `p4` and `p5` doesn't exist. Use `.append()` to add values to those lists

Comment: Either declare p4 and p5 as a list of length p2 e.g. `p4 = [0 for _ in range(len(p2))`, or use `p4.append(p2[x])`

Comment: i want to p2 split them into p4 and p5

Comment: i have edited that my self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an solution to my question,
The answer is

```
def premium_users_checker():
    premium_user1r = open('premium_user.txt', 'r')
    p2 = []
    p4 = []
    p5 = []
    for data in premium_user1r:
        p2.append(data)
    for i in range(len(p2)):
        x1 = int(i)
        p10, p11 = p2[x1].split(' ')
        p4.append(p10), p5.append(p11)
    print(p4, p5)
```

If anyone have problem use this simple fix,
create two variables,
place them in a for loop where the loop splits the lists into two.
save the number one by one on the variables and append them on the list.
you got them thats all.

Comment: Your basic problem is that your original code was trying to extend a list by assigning values to a nonexistent element. Python lists won't do that. The list element must exist before you can assign a value to it.

Comment: Okay sir, but I found a way sir.

Comment: Yes, you did, andthe solution was correct. But the way you described your fix as a "trick" suggested to me that you didn't fully understand why your original code was not doing what you expected. Building up a list using `append` isn't a trick, it is how  lists work.

Comment: @BoarGules i changed to fix sir.
and thank you helping sir.